# Does $f'(x) =0$ imply $f(x) = const$ for every domain?

Tags: derivatives

For $f : [a;b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $f'(x) =0$ implies $f(x) = const$ but what when domain is not an interval?

Comment: For disconnected domains, the statement is false.

Comment: A function from a *closed* interval $J$ is differentiable if it can be extended to a differentiable function some open interval $I$ that contains $J$.

Comment: This is true for every open CONNECTED subset of the domain. If the domain is not connected, then the function might not be constant. For example, take $f(x)=0$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(2,3)$.